# Invisible but clickable drop down box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Is it possible to do this in css/jquery?

I want a drop box that is invisible so there is no arrow or the selected text. Basically if you click on the area, the drop down list will open up so you can select one of the choice. After you select an option, I will do something.

Nothing should be showing if it is not open. And if it is open, only the drop down is showing and not the currently selected.

EDIT:When its open, I want it look like the right and not the left in this image:
http://i.minus.com/iBLX1F1Au1Rt7.png

Comment: So you want this invisible area to look like any other part of the page unless clicked?  Just want to make sure I have this right.

Comment: Yes, it should be invisible until it is open. And even after it is open, it should look like the right image: http://i.minus.com/iBLX1F1Au1Rt7.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apply an opacity = 0 to the select ?

Comment: Strange. This got me exactly what I wanted. Very simple and clean. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Start by using **visibility: hidden** rather than **display: none**

Answer (score 0):

That's a strange requirement, but you could probably toggle css the drop down's visibility property onclick.

```
<select id="dropdown" style="visibility:hidden"></select>

$("#dropdown").click(function() { 
     var visibility = $(this).css("visibility") == "hidden" ?  "visible" : "hidden";
     $(this).css("visibility", visibility);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work: 
**CSS:**

```
.invisible{
    color : transparent;
    background: transparent;
    display : block;
    width : 10px;
    height : 10px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.invisible').on('click',function(){
    openDropDownList();
});

$('.option').on('click',function(){
    youWillDoSomething();
});
```